# Where is "--localcacert" in Puppet man page?

Tags: man, puppet

I am new to Puppet. We have a command and it uses the `--localcacert` option. The command looks like this:

```
puppet agent -t --localcacert <path to CA cert> --ca_server <CA server hostname> --onetime --waitforcert 30
```

I want to know what the option `--localcacert` do but it is not in the man page.

It's not even here: https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/man/agent

nor here: https://linux.die.net/man/8/puppet-agent

Why? The above command works, so therefore it is recognized by `puppet` as a valid option, but why is it not in the man page?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation [is there](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/configuration#localcacert):

> `localcacert`
>
> Where each client stores the CA certificate.
>
> - Default: `$certdir/ca.pem`

along with [this](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/config_about_settings#settings-on-the-command-line) [emphasis mine]:

> Settings from the command line have top priority, and always override settings from the config file. When a Puppet command or service is started, **you can specify any setting as a command line option**.
>
> **Settings require two hyphens and the name of the setting on the command line**

Note: the links above are for version 5.5 because your first link uses this version. Newer links: [`localcacert`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/configuration#localcacert), [command line](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/config_about_settings#settings-command-line).

Comment: oh, so --localcacert is a setting rather than an option?

Comment: @Noob_Guy It seems so. This is my first contact with Puppet, I know nothing about it, I'm just not-too-bad in finding information, documentation and such.

Comment: @Noob_Guy If you are writing it with two dashes like that, I would call it a command line option rather than a setting. Settings are not written with preceding dashes. In this case, though, I would say that each option has a corresponding setting, and vice versa.